# Python derived class intricacies

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I have parent class `Xyzzy` and a derivative class [derived from Xyzzy] `Yappy` as follows:

```
class Xyzzy(object):
    def __init__(self, which_factory):
        self.which_factory = which_factory

    @classmethod
    def factory_foo(cls):
        return cls('factory_foo')

    @classmethod
    def factory_bar(cls):
        return cls('factory_bar')


class Yappy(Xyzzy):
    def __init__(self, which_factory):
        super(Yappy, self).__init__(which_factory)
        print(which_factory)
```

When I print them only the `Yappy` class prints out the factory type not `Xyzzy`:

```
print(Xyzzy.factory_foo())
print(Xyzzy.factory_bar())
print('/-----------/')
print(Yappy.factory_foo())
print(Yappy.factory_bar())
```

And I get:

```
>>> Xyzzy.factory_foo()
<__main__.Xyzzy object at 0x0482F430>
>>> Xyzzy.factory_bar()
<__main__.Xyzzy object at 0x0482F430>
>>> Yappy.factory_foo()
factory_foo
<__main__.Yappy object at 0x0482F3D0>
>>> Yappy.factory_bar()
factory_bar
<__main__.Yappy object at 0x0482F3D0>
```

Could someone explain why the “factory type” is printed by the derived class `Yappy` and not by the parent class `Xyzzy`?

Comment: Could you explain what you were expecting, and why this wasn't it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can’t understand why “print(which_factory)” returns “factory_foo” and “factory_bar” respectively.

Comment: ...as opposed to *what*, exactly - what were you expecting that lead you to be surprised by this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don’t get what “value” is assigned to “self.which_factory” that results “factory_foo” and “factory_bar”.

Comment: The ones you explicitly pass in to `__init__` from your class methods, perhaps? I really can't see why you expected anything other than the outcome you got.

Comment: @jonrsharpe when I call `Xyzzy('some var').factory_foo()` nothing is printed but when I call `Yappy('some var').factory_foo()` I get `some var factory_foo`

Comment: Yes, and I **still can't see why you'd expect any different!** You instantiate a `Yappy` instance, calling `Yappy.__init__` where the argument gets printed, then call its class method which creates another instance, and as `cls is Yappy` in the class method the same `__init__` gets called and prints as programmed. In `Xyzzy` you don't have a `print`, so nothing gets printed. **Why is that suprising?!**

Comment: @jonrsharpe I expect some var to get printed not `factory_foo`. Why `factory_foo` is printed after `some var`?

Comment: Because you call a class method that returns a new instance, which means calling `__init__`, which means calling `print`. If you did `Yappy('some var')` you'd just get `some var`. If you did `Yappy.factory_foo()` you'd just get `factory_foo`. If you do `Yappy('some var').factory_foo()`, **you get both**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so, the `factory_foo()` return value `factory_foo` is passed as an argument to the print function in the `Yappy` constructor. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not wholly clear on what's confusing you, but perhaps seeing a more specific path through the code will help:

```
class Xyzzy(object):

    def __init__(self, which_factory):
        print('calling Xyzzy.__init__')
        self.which_factory = which_factory

    @classmethod
    def factory_foo(cls):
        print('calling factory_foo with', cls)
        return cls('factory_foo')

    @classmethod
    def factory_bar(cls):
        print('calling factory_bar with', cls)
        return cls('factory_bar')


class Yappy(Xyzzy):

    def __init__(self, which_factory):
        print('calling Yappy.__init__')
        super(Yappy, self).__init__(which_factory)
        print(which_factory)
```

In use:

```
>>> Xyzzy('some var')
calling Xyzzy.__init__
<__main__.Xyzzy object at 0x02B8DCD0>

>>> Xyzzy.factory_foo()
calling factory_foo with <class '__main__.Xyzzy'>
calling Xyzzy.__init__
<__main__.Xyzzy object at 0x02A4BE70>

>>> Xyzzy('some var').factory_foo()
calling Xyzzy.__init__
calling factory_foo with <class '__main__.Xyzzy'>
calling Xyzzy.__init__
<__main__.Xyzzy object at 0x02A55C50>


>>> Yappy('some var')
calling Yappy.__init__
calling Xyzzy.__init__
some var
<__main__.Yappy object at 0x02B8DD10>

>>> Yappy.factory_foo()
calling factory_foo with <class '__main__.Yappy'>
calling Yappy.__init__
calling Xyzzy.__init__
factory_foo
<__main__.Yappy object at 0x02A55C50>

>>> Yappy('some var').factory_foo()
calling Yappy.__init__
calling Xyzzy.__init__
some var
calling factory_foo with <class '__main__.Yappy'>
calling Yappy.__init__
calling Xyzzy.__init__
factory_foo
<__main__.Yappy object at 0x02A4BE70>
```

Comment: I was really stuck with that. I got it now.

Comment: @anarchos78 note that you can stick `print` calls wherever you like, it's often very helpful for figuring out the flow. You could also use something like http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Answer (score 4):

You print it yourself in the `__init__` of `Yappy`:

```
class Yappy(Xyzzy):
    def __init__(self, which_factory):
        super(Yappy, self).__init__(which_factory)
        print(which_factory)
```

The `Xyzzy` class has no such `print()` call.